# PHPMyAdmin and ed25519

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, ed25519

I've set a webserver for databases with PHPMyAdmin but one of my nodes use ed25519 plugin to authenticate users. PhPMA doesn't let me use this plugin by default :

> mysqli::real_connect(): **The server requested authentication method
> unknown to the client [client_ed25519]**

> mysqli::real_connect():
> (HY000/2054): **The server requested authentication method unknown to
> the client**

Is it possible to use phpMyAdmin with this mode?

Comment: I don't think so. PHP doesn't have support for this.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you need to add below code to the /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

You also need to update the user authentication method by the following code in mysql

```
alter user 'username'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'password';
```

Change 'password' by your personal MySQL Password

Comment: Thank's man but i need to use another plugin because mysql_native_password is not very secure

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you wouldn't need to change the default in my.cnf, only alter the specific user that needs to be changed.